# Problem with background worker

Tags: c#, user-interface, multithreading, backgroundworker, invoke

Say I have the following class/Form (semi psuedo):

```
public partial class X : Form
{
    private DataTable dt;
    private BackgroundWorker bg;

    public X()
    {
        dt.Columns.Add("A");
        dt.Columns.Add("B");
        dt.Columns.Add("C"); 
    }

    private void button_Click(...)
    {
        bg = new BackgroundWorker();  
        bg.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(bg_DoWork);
        bg.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    private void bg_DoWork(...)
    {
        // do some stuff  
        MagicMethod(parameters);

        // doesnt work, how to fix this?
        dataGridView1.Invoke((Action)delegate { dataGridView1.DataSource = dt; });
    }

    private void MagicMethod(params)
    {
        // update a label, WORKS 
        label1.Invoke((Action) delegate { label1.Text = "somestuff" }

        // do some stuff to fill the datatable
    } 
}
```

Ofcourse this is a distilled version, without the BackgroundWorker everything is sound, but since I want a more responsive UI I try to implement one. But the grid doesnt get updated by the worker (whereas the label does correctly). Any tips?

Comment: If you could provide a short but *complete* example, it would be easier to help you.

Comment: Activate Debug>Exceptions>Common Language Runtime Exceptions>Thrown and check what is failing. The code you provided works.

Answer (score 1):

You may very well be causing an exception somewhere (probably inside MagicMethod) and because you don't handle the Bgw RunWorkerCompleted event you don't notice it.

So, add a RunWorkerCompleted event and check if  `e.Error != null`

The completed event is also a convenient and safe place to process the results: `dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;`

See [this MSDN example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) and pay attention to the if/else if/else pattern in the RunWorkerCompleted event.

Comment: I don't get it, I don't get an apparant error in the RunWorkerCompleted event :s

Comment: And how about a `dataGridView1.DataSource != null` check in Completed? We're down to investigative debugging now.

Comment: When I check the locals I find that the DataSource contains 52 rows.
HasErrors is set to false, but still no cigar. My lack of experience with threading really shows here :(
I posted the code in the reply under this on.

Comment: I know the data are lost between the worker and UI thread, somehow, I just can't seem to figure out why and where hehe

Comment: Please distinguish Grid.DataSource and the Table.

Comment: The DataTable (responseTable) contains data,